# How to show the first low of Kepler's laws

Tags: orbital-motion, popular-science

Picture below is from the  Kepler's laws of Wiki. I fail to found its proof. I mean that how to use 
$$
F=G\frac{Mm}{r^2} ~~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~~~ F=ma
$$
to prove the orbit of planet must be so.

I just be inquisitive mathematic student, and  want to prove some familiar physical sense, for example, the orbit of planet is ellipse. Whether there is some book is talk about proof of familiar physical sense ?  Thanks.

> [image]

Comment: To start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_orbit

Comment: @MarkH  Thanks very much. Do you know any book about the familiar physical sense  ?